# Crop to specific size (not a ratio of it) in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cc-2014, crop

I'd like to crop several images to a specific size. Previously, I would set the size in the crop tool and happily run through a few images and have them all crop to the same specific size.

Now it seems Photoshop wants to crop to a ratio of the specific dimensions. The final output is technically correct in that it's the right size but I want the crop tool to resize to the exact dimensions I've entered and not try to auto-fit to the current image with a ratio.

For example, I have an image that is `300 x 200 x 72`. I want to crop it to `150 x 100 x 72` and have the crop tool appear as those exact dimensions, not as a ratio of them relative to the current image size.

I'm attaching a screenshot of what is happening, to help explain. I don't want this, I want the crop box to be the exact size I've specified so that I don't have to re-size the crop box for each image.

[image: CC (2014) Crop Example]

Comment: The marquee tool and the image crop solved it my similar issue

Answer (score 10):

Since cropping can occur anywhere, and Photoshop introduced more on-the-fly interpolation of pixels to assist those unfamiliar with w+h+ppi restrictions, the proportional aspects of the crop tool are there to allow users to crop any part of the image and the result will be what is set in the Control/Options bar. In reality, I think many users are unaware that setting all 3 fields can cause their image to be interpolated.

It doesn't really matter what size (proportionately) you draw the crop box. The resulting, cropped, image will be whatever size/resolution you've set once you commit to the crop.

If you want a specific size selection, without proportional adjustments in the tool, use the **Marquee Tool** and set a "Fixed Size" in the Control/Options Bar. Then choose `Image > Crop` when your marquee selection is positioned properly.

If all your images require a crop to the center, as your sample image shows, you can use `Image > Canvas Size` and set the final dimensions you require. This will clip the canvas to the size desired.

Things have operated this way since at least CS4, if not earlier, to the best of my recollection.

Comment: I'm aware that there are ways to accomplish this without the crop tool, but I want to be clear that there is no way to set a specific size for the crop tool anymore -- it'll always be a ratio relative to the current image, with output that matches whatever you've set it to.

Comment: Correct, it's always a ratio. The crop tool can not be constrained to a specific size while drawing the crop box. It can only be constrained to a proportion.

Answer (score 2):

new feature in **Photoshop CC (CS6)**:

**Crop Tool** and select a "W x H x Resolution" (Width, Height, Resolution) in the Control/Options Bar.

[image: Select option]

then

[image: set up]

That's it.

You can also save your setting as a preset:

[image: use preset]

Source: [Cropping to an exact size in Photoshop, ultimate Photoshop crop tutorial](http://photoshopcafe.com/tutorials/crop-photoshop)

Answer (score 1):

What I would so if I were you would be to make a template the size you need and drop all of your images in the template. Size or place them to your liking and start saving them out.

This way you can save the psd and make changes to the size later. If you crop and save after you have you image imported you cant make adjustments later. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Change the first box to w x h x resolution and your problems will go away and the crop tool will behave again.

Answer (score 0):

**The easiest way to crop a canvas is probably the oldest way... by going in the "image" menu then "canvas size" and entering your values there.**

You can choose if you want to keep the image centered or not, and use the ratio of not. It's way more precise than selecting the area yourself (unless you need to crop a specific portion.)

[image: canvas size in Photoshop]

---

If you preferred how the crop was working before, maybe you can also try the "use classic mode" for the crop options on the menu.

[image: classic mode cropping in Photoshop]

Answer (score 0):

Simply add "px" after the number in the aspect ratio fields and it will crop and resize to that exact size. Ex: 600 px X 600 px will give you a square 1:1 ratio but also resize the image to 600 px squared.